What is the difference between the differet "or" words in Latin?
What is the difference between the different "or" words in Latin (sive, aut, vel, etc.)?
My teacher has explained it a few times but I keep forgetting and wanted to ask for clarification.

I marked your question as a duplicate of another one where this topic is discussed at length. If you don't find what you need there, please [edit] your question to specify what's missing. This is a good question, as the score of the old question shows!
